# Is it possible to get information about the URL of the caller site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I get information about the url of the site calling an ASP.NET Core Web Api?

Let's say I have a site on http://test.com (App 1) calling http://api.co.uk (App 2)

Is it possible to detect "http://test.com" from App 2?

My code so far:

```
string host = this.AppHelper.HttpContext.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
```

but this return the host of the API, not the caller.

Comment: `Request.Headers["Referer"]` is what you need in .net core

Comment: i think since you will be using cors you can look for the option within it

Comment: Not unless they volunteer the information in a header. How are you being called from that site?

Comment: For now I have control over both api and the site that uses the api, so I perform the calls using HttpClient. But in the future I might let others connect so it would be nice to be able to automatically get the callers host. But for now I send in the host as a parameter

Comment: Short answer: No. There's no reliable way to obtain this information. You might potentially be able to get it from the `Referer` header, but 1) the client must actually provide it, which they may not and 2) even if it is provided, it can be spoofed.

Comment: What is it that you're *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a webshop app that can be used by different Stores. Store entity contains Host, which determines which Store to use. So I thought if I could determine the Host without supplying it, it would be a nice feature. But if it can't be done, I'll just stick with supplying the Host as a parameter.

Comment: I assume that your API is protected. In that case you should be able to identify the client app there.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. I was just curious if it was possible. I now rely on Key and Password to identify the Store object

Comment: How would one do this? Via auth token?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static string GetCallerHost(this HttpContext context)
    {
        var callerFeatures = context.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
        var callerHostIp = callerFeatures?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString()
        var callerHostPort = callerFeatures?.RemotePort.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be overkill, since he's got `HttpContext` he should just access the `Connection` property. Remote IP and Port are there.